# How to match a string after a token (using regex)?

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to extract mail addresses after a token 'eaddr:'. So it would match the all occurrences in line entries, first consecutive string without spaces after that token: I tried:

```
SELECT regexp_substr(tab.entry, 'eaddr:\(.*?\)',1,1,'e',1)
from (
select 'String, email@domain.com' as entry
union
select 'eaddr:mail1@domain.com eaddr:mail2@domain.com sometext     eaddr:   mail3@domain.com some4354% text' as entry
union
select 'eaddr:mail5@domain.org' as entry
union
select 'Just a string' as entry
) tab
;
```

but it does not work. The correct result set is:

```
null
mail1@domain.com mail2@domain.com mail3@domain.com
mail5@domain.org
null
```

Comment: could this `eaddr:   mail3@domain.com` be possibility? I mean whitespace between `eaddr:` and mail address?

Comment: What flavour of SQL is this?

Comment: Any SQL dialect applies here, so if you have ideas solving this with some other function that is OK too. I’m using Snowflake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I suggest using a better regex to verify the email format. I am inspired by Gordon's SPLIT_TO_TABLE + LATERAL approach, and wrote some sample queries to fetch those emails from the entries.

If you want to get all the emails together, you can use this one:

```
with t as (
select 'String, email@domain.com' as entry
union
select 'eaddr:mail1@domain.com eaddr:mail2@domain.com sometext     eaddr:   mail3@domain.com some4354% text' as entry
union
select 'eaddr:mail5@domain.org' as entry
union
select 'Just a string' as entry
) 
Select LISTAGG( regexp_substr( s.value, '[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}' ) ,' ' ) emails from t,
lateral SPLIT_TO_TABLE(t.entry, 'eaddr:') s
where s.seq > 1;

+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                               EMAILS                                |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
| mail1@domain.com mail2@domain.com mail3@domain.com mail5@domain.org |
+---------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

To get the exact result in your question, you can use the following query:

```
with t as (
select 'String, email@domain.com' as entry
union
select 'eaddr:mail1@domain.com eaddr:mail2@domain.com sometext     eaddr:   mail3@domain.com some4354% text' as entry
union
select 'eaddr:mail5@domain.org' as entry
union
select 'Just a string' as entry
) 
select emails from 
(
Select t.entry, s.*, 
LISTAGG( regexp_substr( IFF(s.seq = 1, '', s.value ), '[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,64}' ) ,' ' ) 
OVER ( PARTITION BY s.seq ) emails
from t,
lateral SPLIT_TO_TABLE(t.entry, ' ') s ) 
where index = 1;

+----------------------------------------------------+
|                       EMAILS                       |
+----------------------------------------------------+
| NULL                                               |
| mail1@domain.com mail2@domain.com mail3@domain.com |
| NULL                                               |
| mail5@domain.org                                   |
+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can return only one match at a time from REGEXP_SUBSTR. The code below:

```
with tab(entry) as  (
select 'String, email@domain.com' from dual
union
select 'eaddr:mail1@domain.com eaddr:mail2@domain.com sometext     eaddr:   mail3@domain.com some4354% text'  from dual
union
select 'eaddr:mail5@domain.org'  from dual
union
select 'Just a string'  from dual
) 
SELECT
      regexp_substr(entry, 'eaddr:\s*(\S*)\s*',1,1,'i',1)
      || coalesce(' ' || regexp_substr(entry, 'eaddr:\s*(\S*)\s*',1,2,'i', 1), '')
      || coalesce(' ' || regexp_substr(entry, 'eaddr:\s*(\S*)\s*',1,3,'i', 1), '') as match,
      regexp_count(entry, 'eaddr:\s*(\S*)\s*') as nmatches
      from tab
```

gives the result below (using Oracle). You can use REGEXP_COUNT as shown to get the number of matches. If there are more than 3 email addresses, you can add more `|| coalesce(` lines as needed.

[image]

P.S. I'm not sure what the 'e' flag does in your example. I'm guessing that is a Snowflake-specific value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to split the strings, extract the emails, and then reaggregate.  I don't have Snowflake on hand, but this or something similar should do:

```
select t.*, s.emails
from t left join lateral
     (select list_agg(split(s.value, ' ')), ' ') as emails
      from table(string_split_to_table(t.entry, 'eaddr:')) as s
     ) s;
```

I'm not 100% sure that Snowflake supports multiple-character delimiters, for instance.  If that is the case, you can use:

```
select t.*, s.emails
from t left join lateral
     (select list_agg(substr(s.value, 7), ' ') as emails
      from table(string_split_to_table(t.entry, ' ')) as s
      where value like 'eaddr:%'
     ) s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Javascript UDF

```
    create or replace function ext_mail(col VARCHAR)
                                      returns varchar 
                                      language javascript
                                      as
                                      $$
                                      var y = COL.match(/(?!eaddr):(\s+)?\w+@\w+/g);
                                      if (y) {
                                      ext_out =  y.join(' ');
                                      return ext_out.replace(/:|\s+/g,' ') 
                                      }
                                      else return 'NULL'
                                      $$
                                      ;



with t as (
                                  select 'String, email@domain.com' as entry
                                  union
                                  select 'eaddr:mail1@domain.com eaddr:mail2@domain.com sometext     eaddr:   mail3@domain.com some4354% text' as entry
                                  union
                                  select 'eaddr:mail5@domain.org' as entry
                                  union
                                  select 'Just a string' as entry
                                  ) select ext_mail(ENTRY) from t;
```